# Linebreaks as delimiters in Python numpy's loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy

For example, my data file is like this:

```
Bahman Rhett
Mandla Devyn
Loukil
Zoran Nahuel
```

because loadtxt uses whitespace as the delimiter it separates names with surnames, how can i make linebreaks the delimiters? Another problem is that not all rows have the same amout of "columns", so it gives error. Should i use something other than numpy for this job?

Comment: There's a `sep` parameter

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) to load the data file using [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). If you need a numpy array type, pandas then makes it easy to convert from a pandas dataframe to a numpy array with [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html).

```
# header = None indicates there is no header row
df = pandas.read_csv(DATA_FILE, header=None)

# or if you want to name the column:
df = pandas.read_csv(DATA_FILE, names=["my-col"])

# if you need it as numpy array type, you can convert via:
arr = df.to_numpy()
```

printing the dataframe shows:

```
         my-col
0  Bahman Rhett
1  Mandla Devyn
2        Loukil
3  Zoran Nahuel
```

Comment: Problem with that aproach is that my files are in txt and not csv and unless i make a .bat file turning all the files from txt to csv, i don't think i can use pandas' method.

Comment: @BasicDonut text files aren't a problem; really csv is just a text format too, the extension just gives you an idea of how it's supposed to be used and the format of the text inside. when i tried this out myself, i was just using a basic `.txt` file too